# adding Artifactory.newServer to jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I would like to instantiate a an instance of a Artifactory.newServer object in a jenkins pipeline. This object is instantiated like so

```
def rtServer = Artifactory.newServer url: SERVER_URL, credentialsId: CREDENTIALS
```

My question is where do I set the `SERVER_URL` and `CREDENTIALS` in jenkins. The documentation on the jenkins plugin does elaborate on this:  https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Configuring+Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in, but I need some help understanding how to reference the environment variables in the Jenkins file itself. I am using a simple pipeline job. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Environment variables can be accessed with ‘env.’  You could just hardcode the server url and credentialsID into the pipeline itself. Or get them from parameters etc

Comment: You can define the parameters in the Job's UI:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to instantiate a server object is like so

```
rtServer = Artifactory.newServer url: 'server', username: username , password: password
```

To set this up properly you'll need to go to **Manage Jenkins** select the artifactory plugin and create a new artifactory server. After I did that everything worked just fine.